# hide objects inside array using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-hide

i am working with MEAN stack, i have number of entries of a user inside an array like:

```
 { bankDetails: [],
  academics: [ [Object], [Object] ],
   trainings: [ [Object] ],
   username: 'sfdf@gmail.afsadfcom',
   accessLevel: 'worker',
   __v: 0},`
 { bankDetails: [],
  academics: [ [Object], [Object] ],
  trainings: [ [Object] ],
  username: 'acbckd@gmail.afsadfcom',
   accessLevel: 'admin',
    __v: 0} and many objects like these.
```

which i get from server and stored in vm.empDetails:

```
 $http.get('/employee').then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.data);
         vm.empDetails = res.data;
    }, function(err) {
         console.log(err);
     });
```

now what i have done in html file is :

```
  <tr ng-repeat="res in vm.empDetails track by $index">             
           <td>{{res.firstName}} {{res.lastName}}</td>
              <td>{{res.jobTitle}}</td>
               <td><md-button ng-click="vm.manageProfile(res._id)">Manage</md-button></td></tr>
```

i am getting all the data that are stored in employee collection and can show them. *All i am Trying to do* is show only entries whose **access_level = "worker"**          and want to hide the users with **access_level="admin"** . how can i do so?? any suggestion and comments are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="res in vm.empDetails track by $index" ng-show="res.access_level === 'worker'"> 
  // something
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="res in vm.empDetails track by $index | filter:customFilter">
```

You can use a `customFilter` to filter out the items whose `access_level` is admin

```
app.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function( items ) {
      var filtered = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if(item.hasOwnProperty("access_level") && !item.access_level === "admin")
            filtered.push(item);
      });
      return filtered;
    };
});
```

Comment: Angular `filter` can track the item's properties and filter according to the value you pass. No need for custom filter.

Comment: @AranS: You don't need... but sometimes its better to have your own customFilter coz it gives more advantage of playing with other business rules getting applied to same object... its just a choice and a decision.

Comment: i made it, you guys rocks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="res in vm.empDetails track by $index | filter: {accessLevel: 'worker'})">             
           <td>{{res.firstName}} {{res.lastName}}</td>
              <td>{{res.jobTitle}}</td>
               <td><md-button ng-click="vm.manageProfile(res._id)">Manage</md-button></td></tr>
```